# how to create <ul> thing for each 10 <li> created?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I need to create every 10 records of the new `<ul>` to store the rest.
The idea is that every 10 `<li>` he creates another `<ul>` block that will contain 10 more and so on.

What is returned from the bank in blade:
[image]

As I'm trying to do with the following result now:
[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are expected to attempt to solve the problem on your own first. Then, if you fail, try researching why and how to fix it. When all else fails, come here, present what you have tried in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), explain how it fails and what you expect instead.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are expected to attempt to solve the problem on your own first. Then, if you fail, try researching why and how to fix it. When all else fails, come here, present what you have tried in the form of an MCVE, explain how it fails and what you expect instead

Comment: Could you please post your code as text and not as image so that your question is still understandable even if the image is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Via [`array_chunk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk) you can split your array into chunks of 10 items (or less if it's the last chunk).

```
@php
    $chunks = array_chunk($category->recursiveChildren, 10);
@endphp

@foreach($chunks as $chunk)
    <ul>
        @foreach($chunk as $child)
            <li>{{ $child }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```